# How to simplify real number terms in Coq?

Tags: coq, real-number

I am trying to do simple proofs for real numbers with Coq. For example, I want to prove the average of two non-negative numbers is also non-negative.

```
Example test: forall r1 r2:R, r1 >= 0 -> r2 >= 0 -> (r1 + r2)/2 >= 0.
```

My first step is to prove `r1 + r2 >=0` as follows.

```
Require Export Coq.Reals.RIneq.
Require Export Coq.Reals.R_sqrt.

Local Open Scope Z_scope.
Local Open Scope R_scope.

Example test: forall r1 r2:R, r1 >= 0 -> r2 >= 0 -> (r1 + r2)/2 >= 0.
Proof. intros. 
  assert (r1 + r2 >= 0 + 0).
  apply Rplus_ge_compat; assumption. simpl in H1.
```

However, I can only get

```
...
H1 : r1 + r2 >= 0 + 0
______________________________________(1/1)
(r1 + r2) / 2 >= 0
```

in the hypothesis. I can't change `0 + 0` on the RHS of H1 to `0`. I tried `simpl in H1.` as shown and it did nothing. I understand that real numbers are different from `nat`. But how should I simplify things here?

(Note: I am beginner at real numbers. And the code above may be naive/inefficient. Suggestions for improvement are welcome. )
Also:

```
Rplus_ge_compat
     : forall r1 r2 r3 r4 : R,
       r1 >= r2 ->
       r3 >= r4 -> r1 + r3 >= r2 + r4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real numbers in Coq's standard library are axiomatic and as such *do not* compute. But you can rewrite by some theorems to simplify the expression:

```
rewrite Rplus_0_r in H1.
```

Or rely on tactics applying various rewrite steps to turn expressions into a normal form. To simplify expressions on a ring, you may use `ring_simplify`.

```
ring_simplify in H1.
```

If you are not limited to ring operations but also have fractions, you can use `field_simplify` instead (in this case it won't lead to the normal form you are looking for):

```
field_simplify in H1.
```

Another possibility is to use `replace ... with ...` to state precisely what you want replaced and by what you want it replaced. If you readily know how to prove that the two expressions are equal `replace ... with ... by ...` will let you discharge that constraint immediately.

```
replace (0 + 0) with 0 in H1 by ring.
```